# Why can't I get the camera to show?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Followed this simple code from several tutorials, all of which are very similar, but I cant for the life of me get this to do anything other than show a blank UIViewController. self.imagePicker is defined in the .h file, given a property, and then synthesized as normal:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {



    // Create image picker controller
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    // Set source to the camera
    self.imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // Delegate is self
    //imagePicker.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"%@", self.imagePicker);

    // Show image picker
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try loading your UIImagePickerView in somewhere other than `viewDidLoad`. In the past I have seen things like blank UIViewController's and other wacky ViewController behavior when you present a viewcontroller within the viewDidload method of another. Perhaps try the UIViewController method `viewDidAppear` instead. If doesn't work, put it in an entirely seperate method that you call with a slight delay once the presenting viewcontroller has been loaded.

Comment: Ahh amazing, yes this seems to have fixed it. I launched the camera after pressing a button and this works fine now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: It's been a few weeks, but if this solved your problem can you please mark my answer as correct. I need reputation on StackOverflow...that's how things work here if your unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

You are setting the picker to the library, you need to set it to the camera.

```
self.imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

EDIT: However, this doesn't explain why you'd get a blank view.

Try calling `[super viewDidLoad]` before presenting the picker.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both of these things. It's still just a completely blank screen. (Btw, I am testing on a real device, not in the simulator). Very very confused here....

Answer (score 0):

Also, setting a property that retains with an init call is an automatic memory leak.

This is because you end up with a retain count of two.  One for the init and one for the retain.   Create a variable, assign it to your property and then release it.

Just an FYI.

Comment: Ah thanks Jason -  I have seen that technique used elsewhere and never understood why people did it - now I do! Thanks.